# What is this object type and how to get it's value?

Tags: angular, typescript

`const error= { 'aaa': ['bbb', fieldName] };`

What type is this? and how can I get `'bbb'`?

Comment: Please elaborate your question ,rest you can do this to get `bbb` 
 `console.log(error["aaa"][0])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a plain javascript object (I'm assuming you're using TypeScript and have not specified a class/type/interface for this).

`error.aaa` is an array with the elements `['bbb', fieldName]`. Arrays are special types of objects.

You can access `'bbb'` through `error.aaa[0]`. (Or `error["aaa"][0]`, as @Pardeep Jain has suggested)

Answer (score 1):

Its simply a javascript object type variable with key value pair, and you can access value  like this -

```
error["aaa"][0]
```

or

```
error.aaa[0]
```